# Trouble setting up Qt 6.5.0 LTS for static compilation

Tags: qt, qt6, qtwidgets

I'm currently trying to set up a Docker container containing Qt 6.5.0 LTS. My goal is to statically compile Qt programs using qmake, so that I don't have to install any dependencies to run the executable. However, I'm facing some issues and need assistance with the following error messages:

```
./echoWebSocket: error while loading shared libraries: libQt6Widgets.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

or

```
./echoWebSocket: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Widgets.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

To address this problem, I added the staticlib flag to the .pro file:

```
CONFIG += staticlib
```

However, when I build the project, I encounter the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: attempted static link of dynamic object `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:149: echoWebSocket] Error 1
```

Can someone please guide me on how to install the static version of the libQt5Widgets and libQt6Widgets libraries?

Below is the configuration command I used for the ./configure step:

```
./configure -commercial \
            -release \
            -static \
            -static-runtime \
            -static-libgcc \
            -static-libstdc++ \
            -reduce-relocations \
            -no-pch \
            -prefix "/qt-${QT_VERSION_B}-static" \
            -no-rpath \
            -fontconfig \
            -nomake tests \
            -nomake examples \
            -skip qtwebengine \
            -skip qtdoc \
            -skip qttools \
            -skip qtwebkit-example \
            -skip qtsensors \
            -skip qttranslations \
            -skip qtpdf
```

I would greatly appreciate any assistance you can provide. Thank you!